# Relationship tables with Entity Framework, SQL Server and VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a problem and I can't solved it. I want to show a datagridview with a entity called `usuarios` that is related to the `perfiles` entity, each user has an assigned profile, in the profile table is the description.

But when I want to show the information in DGV only shows me the information about `Usuarios`. How can I show the description that is in the other entity `perfiles`?

I use Entity Framework and I use `usuariosDataBindings` for the DGV

When I find the columns available shows me something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4diNA.png)

I tried to manually add the property `descripcion`, but it returns nothing:

[Property added manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNKji.png)

This is my `model.edmx`, for the backend, I use SQL Server:

[model.edmx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxToq.png)

This is my formload method:

```
Public Class CrudUsuario

    Private db As BlinkBDEntities
    Private Sub CrudUsuario_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        db = New BlinkBDEntities
        db.usuarios.Load()
        UsuariosBindingSource.DataSource = db.usuarios.Local()
        ComboBox1.DataSource = db.perfil.Local.ToList()
        PanelAgregar.Hide()
        PanelModificar.Hide()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't add language tags unless your post contains that language. There is no evidence of C# here.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I'm gonna remove the tag

Comment: This is why you use view models at the UI rather than entities. You should define a class with the specific shape you want for your UI. You then transfer the data from the entities to instances of that view model and bind them to the UI. In a case like this, that view model may wrap the actual entities, so that any editing done in the UI will update the entities indirectly.